# Can i create a custom HTTP protocol in Delphi?

Tags: flash, delphi, http

I build a project using Flash and Delphi. In Flash i need communication with delphi. Current i use ExternalInterface and FSCommand. Now i need Flash communication with Delphi via HTTP but it need open a custom port on Delphi and it can prevent by user's firewall. I see a product called F-IN-BOX it can implement HTTP link like http://FLV/video.flv then Fash app can load video via that link and dont effect by Firewall.

Anyone know way can do like that?

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand you.

If you need to talk from your Flash app to your Delphi app, maybe you should be looking at RESTful architecture.

HTTP is either on port 80, or you have firewall problems, as you noted. So put it on port 80. Why not port 80?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a packet sniffer (WireShark) or a HTTP proxy ([Don's Proxy](http://donsproxy.moneybender.com/) for example) to see what goes over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve HTTP responses from a Delphi application, you might want to use the [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.html) components and TIdHTTPServer. Your'e free of choice to use the standard port 80 or any other port for your server to listen to.

You'll further need a transportation format. If your targeting Windows on the server-side, MSXML is a good choice for processing XML. Alternatively, use a JSON parser for Delphi like [SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6) or [Delphi Web Objects](http://sourceforge.net/projects/is-webstart/).

If you don't like your application to act as a standalone web server, consider writing it as a CGI or ISAPI application.